# Невозможно экспортировать таблицу mysql в csv

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Вот хочу экспортировать данные из таблицы:

```
SELECT * FROM users
INTO OUTFILE 'D:/filename.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ;
```

но возникает ошибка:

> SELECT * FROM users INTO OUTFILE 'D:/filename.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED
>   BY ';'    Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement 0.000 sec

Как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql

Comment: Не работает етот способ

Comment: Эта фраза не несёт полезной информации...